# How to call the .net web service in Android Application to store and retrive?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

Here i have the c# web service for log in screen to my application where this web service return type is Data Table so how can i write in android part to check the log in detail?can any one help me out Thanks in advance!!

```
public DataTable GetLoginValidation(String UserName,String Password)
{
    String SQL="uspLoginValidation";
    SqlCommand oCommand=new SqlCommand(SQL);
    oCommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.Parameters.clear();
    oCommand.parameters.AddWithVaue("@UserName",UserName);
    oCommand.parameters.AddWithVaue("@Password",Password);

    return GetTable(oCommand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either Restful or Soap service for .net then use volly or restclient library or use httpclient to consume web service in android.